# Verifying Subtraction Closure in the Product of Two Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am attempting to show that the product of two ideals $A$ and $B$, $AB$, is also an ideal.  I've got the underlying set defined as the following:

$$
AB=\left\{ a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots+a_nb_n \mid a_i\in A, b_i \in B, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \right\}
$$

Good so far.  Verifying the $ar, ra \in AB$ requirement is simple enough using associativity.  For whatever reason I'm getting hung up on the subtraction closure.  I'll define $x, y \in AB$ such that:

$$
\begin{align*}
  x&= a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots+a_nb_n \tag{$a_i \in A, b_i \in B$}\\
  y&= c_1d_1+c_2d_2+\dots+c_nd_n \tag{$c_i \in A, d_i \in B$}
\end{align*}
$$

And then I'll take $x - y$:

$$
\begin{align*}
x-y&= a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots+a_nb_n-\left(c_1d_1+c_2d_2+\dots+c_nd_n\right) \\
  &= a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots+a_nb_n-c_1d_1-c_2d_2-\dots-c_nd_n \\
  &= a_1b_1-c_1d_1+a_2b_2-c_2d_2+\dots+a_nb_n-c_nd_n \\
  &= (a_1b_1-c_1d_1)+(a_2b_2-c_2d_2)+\dots+(a_nb_n-c_nd_n)
\end{align*}
$$

So that's where I end up.  Question is: is that enough? (bonus question: have I screwed something up?).  I'm stuck on the idea that I should be able to derive $(a_i-c_i)(b_i-d_i)$ somehow, but I haven't been able to make that happen.  So, at the moment I'm not convinced that $(x-y) \in AB$.

My suspicions are that I've either WAY overthought this, or that I've completely forgotten some middle school math rules that will due the trick.  Either way, insights will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The value of $n$ doesn't necessarily have to be the same between the two elements.

Comment: Hint: if $x=a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2$ and $y = c_1 d_1$, then $x-y = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + (-c_1) d_1$.

Comment: I think that you're on the overthinking side.  $-c_1d_1$ is an element of $AB$ since $-c_1\in A$ and $d_1\in B$.  So, you've already got a sum of terms of the correct form.

Comment: @daniel Okay, so the point of the parentheses is to highlight the fact that $-c_1 \in A$ and $d_1 \in B$?  I don't know why I wanted something more complicated than that.

Comment: And point taken about $n$.  I thought about changing it, but I liked how neat everything turned out, lol

Comment: @DanielSchepler By adding $0$'s, one could make it so that the sums always have the same number of terms, but that's not necessary or very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-y=-\sum c_id_i=\sum(-c_i)d_i\in AB$